# Activate Internet Explorer Tab and click on link

Tags: vba

When I go to one website, I click on one link.

A new tab opens in addition to the existing one.

I need to go to that tab and click on one link.

How can I set that new tab as active IE document?

E.g.
I open below website.
"https://gradeup.co/how-to-fill-ssc-cpo-delhi-police-si-asi-online-application-form-i-5ed24332-b9e6-11e5-adce-a24a34b1a3cf"

I click on "ssconline.nic.in" and a new tab opens. Now I want to click on a "Click to check status" link.

The code opens a new tab however can't click on "Click to check status".

```
Sub activatetab()

    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True

    'Define URL
    URL = "https://gradeup.co/how-to-fill-ssc-cpo-delhi-police-si-asi-online-application-form-i-5ed24332-b9e6-11e5-adce-a24a34b1a3cf"

    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL

    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    'Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    'Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
    While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

    'Click on step 1 :ssconline.nic.in
    Dim myElement As Object

    For Each myElement In IE.document.getelementsbyTagName("a")
        'show the text content of 'tr' element being looked at
        'Debug.Print myElement.outertext
        If myElement.Outertext = "ssconline.nic.in" Then
            myElement.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Click on step 2 :ssconline.nic.in

    Dim oShell              As Object
    Dim oWin                As Object
    Dim i

    i = 1

    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oWin = oShell.Windows()
    'oWin.Item(i).Quit
    Set IE2 = oWin.Item(i)
    'Debug.Print IE2.Text

    Dim myElement1 As Object

    For Each myElement1 In IE2.document.getelementsbyTagName("a")
        'show the text content of 'tr' element being looked at
        Debug.Print myElement1.Outertext
        If myElement1.Outertext = "Click to check status" Then
            myElement1.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: why don't you just go to `ssconline.nic.in` in the first place?   the `https://gradeup.co/how-to-fill-ssc-cpo-de.....` appears to be only an instruction web page  ........

Comment: Actually this is just a example. I use some other application and in that I will need to use this functionality.

Comment: understood. do not click on link in the first page. obtain the URL only. then just do `IE.Navigate URL` to the second page

Comment: Actually I tried that but the problem is that to find elements on that page, I need to use following syntax,

Comment: Dim myElement1 As Object
          For Each myElement1 In IE1.document.getelementsbyTagName("a")
                    Debug.Print myElement1.Outertext
                   If myElement1.Outertext = "Click to check status" Then
                   myElement1.Click
                   Exit For
                   End If
         Next

Comment: How can I make that tab active and or create new object e.g. IE1 and refer to that